# Can you Grant select permission to all tables in sql server for a limited time?

Tags: sql-server

So i'm doing this SQL SERVER school project and i want to add to a specific user the right to select for a limited amount of time lets say till 24 September 2016.
Is it possible and if yes how ? 
THANKS!

Comment: you have potentially 3 different sql server technologies above. Name your server and delete the other tags

Answer (score 0):

There is no provision to grant access for a limited amount of time.

Best of luck.

Comment: When ever there is a mention of Time dependant activity in SQL Server, the one thing that jump to your mind is SQL Server agent, I think I have found a way to handle this see my answer:)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is creating a `SQL Server Agent Job`.

1. Create 2 steps in the job one for adding the user to database role `db_datareader` and then anotehr step to take away the role membership of that user.

The step to grant user permission should look something like

```
IF (GETDATE() >= '2016-09-24 08:58:59.000'
    AND GETDATE() <= '2016-09-24 09:01:00.000')
BEGIN
  EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'UserA'
END
```

The second step to revoke user's permission should look something like

```
IF (GETDATE() >= '2016-09-24 16:58:59.000')
BEGIN
  EXEC sp_droprolemember N'db_datareader', N'UserA'
END
```

2. Schedule the job to run twice a day. Occurrence every 8 hours. Assuming you only want the user to have access for 8 hours.
3. In the start date and end date options use `24 September 2016`. So the Job is only executed on that date and never before or after that date.
4. Make sure that the interval between occurrences matches the logic in your IF statement of each step.
5. The job database context should be the database where your user need permissions.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new column with a **date** datatype and call it ***endDate***. You'd insert September 24, 2016 into ***endDate*** for a user and (depending on how you're accessing it) simply use an `if` statement comparing the current date and the end date. For example :-

```
if(CURDATE() < endDate)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd write a job that will run on that date that revokes the user's right.

I would NOT modify the schema to handle a one-off case. Control of rights to the database should be external to the database.